# What is the actual path of actions happening when I press a key on keyboard and it shows on a shell?

Tags: linux, shell, encoding

I am using a generic usb keyboard, Linux 2.6.27 with gnome desktop, gnome-terminal and bash shell. I am interested to know what happens in the software. How are special characters from my keyboard interpreted with some encoding to characters and where do the character pictures come from?

Comment: Whoa. The answer to this can fill easily fill books or even shelves of books, depending on the detail level used.

Comment: @unwind Agreed. This reminds me of my favorite interview question, once posed to me at a networking company. What happens when you open your browser and navigate to a URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Linux input layer with the USB drivers gets scancodes (basically "KEY 1 DOWN" "KEY 1 UP") from the keyboard.

X uses its keymap to convert scancodes into keycodes and X input events.

The GTK input method converts the sequence of input events into composed unicode characters.

Gnome-terminal encodes these in UTF-8 for the shell.

The Shell doesn't care. it just knows that it's dealing with a multibyte encoding.

The shell echoes multibyte-encoded text back through the TTY.

Gnome-terminal decodes the incoming text and determines unicode code points.

Gnome-terminal draws characters using GTK+ facilities.

GTK+ uses Pango to render the text, and calls the X library to draw the pixels to the screen.

The X server draws characters into the screen buffer and the video card displays them.

Here is my attempt at a diagram:

[alt text http://osoft.us/system_layers.png](http://osoft.us/system_layers.png)

Comment: Image is down and no copy on the internet. :(

Answer (score 2):

Look at it in layers. First is the hardware, and a device driver in the Linux kernel will have specific methods for controlling and responding to the keyboard via status registers in the device and interrupt handlers, for example.

Next is the Linux kernel, which will have some method of loading the appropriate driver for each piece of hardware detected at boot time. Once loaded, the device driver conforms to some kernel-driver interface, providing data from the device to the kernel and vice versa.

Outside the kernel, at some level, the device driver and hardware are visible, usually as a listing in the /dev directory. Software, like a terminal emulator, that needs to use a device will gain access to the device through an entry in /dev.

Communication between a user-level application and the device now happens via a series of read/write and ioctl operations. These trap into the kernel (see the manual pages for these for some detail), at which point the kernel communicates with the device driver loaded above.

The terminal emulator will display characters as you type them (in most cases) and as they are received from the device (in most cases) by using fonts that it can access, located in various places depending on the application. (I'm speaking in generalities here because I don't know Gnome specifically).

Does this help?